# mono + hardware interrupts / signals

Tags: mono, embedded, hardware, interrupt-handling

i am working on embedded devices where it is common that you handle some hw interrupt events with c code (like catching a pressed button, or let some LED´s blink), i was wondering if anybody has some experience doing this on mono, c#.

I was thinking about Pinvoke native libraries with the interrupt handlers.

Could this work or has someone other advices?

best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not mono but worth looking at and closest to your requirement is MS .Net Micro Framework. Most popular hardware incarnation is [FEZ Domino](http://www.tinyclr.com/hardware/1/fez-domino). It supports subset of C# and interrupts for supported hardware.

Comment: i have crosscompiled the .netmf sources for arm. In the output directory i got some directories like /any_media and /flash and are about 22,4 mb in size. How do i install it on my board, is it enough just to copy the bins and libs?